# How to include php file instead of url in php redirect

Tags: php, redirect, http-redirect

Instead of such regular redirect:

```
<?php
  header('Location: http://domain.com');
?>
```

...I need to call the URL in from another php file instead of http://domain.com, so something like that:

```
<?php
  header('Location: <?php include("file.php");?>');
?>
```

File.php has the right url in it (generated with API code). But it doesn't read the php code in php redirect. How to make it work?

Comment: Why not include it before and save a variable with your desired domain there and attach that in your header function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**file.php**

```
<?php 
    // Determine your URL and assign it to $url
    $url = "http://example.com"; 
?>
```

**File with header redirect**

```
<?php 
    require_once('file.php');
    header('Location: '.$url);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your php file pass the generated url.

If it use the echo use next:

```
ob_start();
include('file.php');
$output = ob_get_clean();
header('Location: '.$output);
```

Or if it use the return:

```
$return = include('file.php');
header('Location: '.$return);
```